# Attach event to control inside a Placeholder using designer ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, event-handling

Is it possible to add an event to a control which is inside another control, like say a PlaceHolder control **using the designer**?

When the control is alone on the form this works perfectly... you simply add it from the properties window by clicking the thunder icon and clicking on the event needed.

I know I can do by adding it manually but it would just be faster if it were generated for me.
To test this, add the following to a form and try adding the OnClick event of the btnTest through the designer or properties window:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phTest" runat="server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" ID="btnTest" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Any help is appreciated

Regards

Comment: the placeholder seems to hide the thunder tab on properties - interesting finding! :)

Comment: Yes, do you think it's a bug or is there some reason behind this. I just hope it's fixed in 2010. Beta hasn't fixed it yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess there is NO way it can be done through the designer, except by adding the eventhandler to the button before you put it into the Placeholder.
Thanks for the help guys...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phTest" runat="server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" ID="btnTest" OnClick="bUpdate_Click" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I have had to do it manually in my project and as long as you match up the eventargs it was straight forward

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PlaceHolder control is using for this purpose. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz6403ts(VS.71).aspx)

> The PlaceHolder Web server control
>   enables you to place an empty
>   container control within the page and
>   then dynamically add, remove, or loop
>   through child elements at run time.
>   The control only renders its child
>   elements; it has no HTML-based output
>   of its own.

Comment: Yes you are right about this. The problem is when using say a Panel it generates a <div> tag which i do not want. Seems you can specify how to render a control in vs 2010 i.e. whether or not to show specific html tags or not